# Creating a Tangential Arc between 2 intersecting circles and a known point

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have been struggling with the problem of trying to setout a tangential arc between C1 and C2 through point P. I was hoping to find a method of how to solve this either using math or geometry as i need to program it out with some limitations in the software interface.  Further details as per image below, i am aiming for a result similar to the dashed white line in the image with C1 being the center of the yellow circle and C2 being the center of the green with P1 being the desired point to pass through and M being the midpoint between C1 and C2.Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Example]

I've tried a few different methods but I just can't find an answer that works as I change the variables.

Comment: Do circles always have equal radius? Does point P always lie at median perpendicular in inner region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that circles have equal radii `R`, distance from central line to circle centers is `D`, point `P` ordinata is `py`. Example for `R=5, D=3, py=3.39`:

[image]

Small circle through point `P` touches large circle in point `F` (and another circle in point `G`). It's center `E` has ordinate `cy` (unknown yet), and touch point `F` has coordinates `tx, ty` (also unknown yet). Let define vectors

```
CF = (tx+D, ty)
EF = (tx, ty-cy)
```

Vectors `CF` and `EF` are collinear (they are normals to touching circles), so their cross product is zero:

```
(tx+D)*(ty-cy)-ty*tx=0
```

Also we can write two equations for vector lengths as radii of large and small circles:

```
(tx+D)^2+ty^2 = R^2
tx^2+(ty-cy)^2=(py-cy)^2
```

Now we have three equations for three unknowns, and I've put this system into Maple solver

[image]

Result is quite simple. We need only `cy` value.

Note that one (larger) `cy` value corresponds to the case, when `P` is the lowest point of small arc (very small circle above `P`)

Small Python code:

```
D = 3
py = 3.39
R = 5
cy = -1/2*(D**2-R**2+2*py*R-py**2)/(py-R)
r = py - cy
print(cy, r)
cy = 1/2*(R**2+2*R*py+py**2-D**2)/(py+R)
r = abs(py - cy)
print(cy, r)
```

gives

```
1.9900310559006207 1.3999689440993794
3.6586471990464835 0.2686471990464834
```

where the first value is smaller than `py` and we want this value as small circle center (2.0  at my picture). Small radius here: `r=py-cy~1.4`

For your picture values resulting small radius is 5:

```
D = 3.854 / 2
py = 5.536
R = 7
cy = -1/2*(D**2-R**2+2*py*R-py**2)/(py-R)
r = py - cy
print(cy, r)

>> 0.5362134562841512 4.999786543715849
```

Comment: @Impresario_2244 Is my answer unclear?

Comment: Sorry, it took me so long to get back to you but i had been pulled into other work. I have had a chance to sit down and really go over what you have given and it makes sense i will test it out over the next few days. Thanks again for your time and help.